# break lines in bash script on a string containing both single and double quotes

Tags: bash

I have a dockerfile with and entrypoint like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT /opt/my_applicatitons/entry.sh "${URL_1}" \
                                          "${URL_2}" \
                                          "${URL_3}" \
                                          "${DATETIME}" \
                                          "${ID}" \
                                          "${URL_4}" \
                                          "${URL_5}" \
                                          "${S}" \
                                          "${S1}" \
                                          "${I}" \
                                          "${URL_6}" /opt/my_applications/app.py
```

This is my bash script which is inkoved

```
#!/bin/sh

EVENT_BODY='{"param1": "'"$1"'","param2": "'"$2"'","param3": "'"$3"'","param4": "'"$4"'","param5": "'"$5"'", "param6": "'"$6"'", "param7": "'"$7"'", "param8": "'"$8"'","param9": "'"$9"'", "param10": "'"${10}"'", "param11": "'"${11}"'"}'

echo $EVENT_BODY

exec ${12} -e "${EVENT_BODY}"
```

Basically I use the bash script to get all the parameters and construct a JSON that I pass as a single parameter to my python application. I would like to find a more elegant way to do it since the string `EVENT_BODY` is not readable. I tried to break the line using `\` (as I did in the dockerfile) in different location (after single quotes, after double quotes) but none of them works. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings can span multiple lines. No need for backslashes or any other escapes.

###### Direct interpolation (unsafe)

```
# Unsafe! See below.
EVENT_BODY="{
    \"param1\": \"$1\",
    \"param2\": \"$2\",
    \"param3\": \"$3\",
    \"param4\": \"$4\",
    \"param5\": \"$5\",
    \"param6\": \"$6\",
    \"param7\": \"$7\",
    \"param8\": \"$8\",
    \"param9\": \"$9\",
    \"param10\": \"${10}\",
    \"param11\": \"${11}\"
}"
```

You should be aware that interpolating variables directly into JSON is error prone and potentially dangerous. Much like SQL injection, this is prone to breakage if the parameters have special characters such as embedded quotes or backslashes.

Best case, they'll create invalid JSON that fails to parse. Worst case, if these parameters are supplied externally a crafty hacker could supply a value such as `$8` = `param8 value", "param7": "overridden value`. This would cause a  second `param7` key to be added. Some JSON parsers will reject the duplicate key, but some will parse it and potentially override the expected `param7` value.

Demonstration:

```
$ ./entry.sh a b c d e f g 'h": "param7", "hacked' i j k l
{
    "param1": "a",
    "param2": "b",
    "param3": "c",
    "param4": "d",
    "param5": "e",
    "param6": "f",
    "param7": "g",
    "param8": "h", "param7": "hacked",
    "param9": "i",
    "param10": "j",
    "param11": "k"
}
```

###### JQ (safe)

A much better way to generate JSON in a shell script is to use [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON parser. It knows how to escape special characters and prevent JSON injection attacks.

```
EVENT_BODY="$(jq -n \
--arg param1 "$1" --arg param2 "$2" --arg param3 "$3" --arg param4 "$4" --arg param5 "$5" --arg param6 "$6" --arg param7 "$7" --arg param8 "$8" --arg param9 "$9" --arg param10 "${10}" --arg param11 "${11}" \
'{"param1": $param1, "param2": $param2, "param3": $param3, "param4": $param4, "param5": $param5, "param6": $param6, "param7": $param7, "param8": $param8, "param9": $param9, "param10": $param10, "param11": $param11}'
)"

echo "$EVENT_BODY"
```

Demonstration:

```
{
  "param1": "a",
  "param2": "b",
  "param3": "c",
  "param4": "d",
  "param5": "e",
  "param6": "f",
  "param7": "g",
  "param8": "h\", \"param7\": \"hacked",
  "param9": "i",
  "param10": "j",
  "param11": "k"
}
```

You'll likely have to `apt-get install jq` or `yum install jq` in your container to use it -- worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `app.py` to [take arguments on the command line, or from the environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-names-command-line-arguments-and-environment-variables)? The JSON input isn't doing anything useful just being a flat dictionary with generic `param1`, `param2`, etc. keys.

###### Command line

Get rid of `ENTRYPOINT` and use `CMD`.

```
CMD /opt/my_applications/app.py \
    "$URL_1" \
    "$URL_2" \
    "$URL_3" \
    "$DATETIME" \
    "$ID" \
    "$URL_4" \
    "$URL_5" \
    "$S" \
    "$S1" \
    "$I" \
    "$URL_6"
```

In Python, access the arguments in `sys.argv`:

```py
url1 = sys.argv[0]
url2 = sys.argv[1]
url3 = sys.argv[2]
...
```

(Or even better, use a command line parser such as [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).)

###### Environment

Set environment variables in the Dockerfile. Get rid of `ENTRYPOINT` and just use `CMD`:

```
ENV URL_1=...
ENV URL_2=...
ENV URL_3=...
...

CMD /opt/my_applications/app.py -e "$EVENT_BODY"
```

In Python, access the variables from `os.environ`.

```py
url1 = os.environ['URL_1']
url2 = os.environ['URL_2']
url3 = os.environ['URL_3']
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> EVENT_BODY='{"param1": "'"$1"'","param2": "'"$2"'","param3":
> "'"$3"'","param4": "'"$4"'","param5": "'"$5"'", "param6": "'"$6"'",
> "param7": "'"$7"'", "param8": "'"$8"'","param9": "'"$9"'", "param10":
> "'"${10}"'", "param11": "'"${11}"'"}'

Actually this is already multi-string, not the single string, so you can divide it after any paired single quote, like this:

```
EVENT_BODY='{"param1": "'"$1"\
 '","param2": "'"$2"\
 '","param3": "'\
 "$3"\
 '","param4": "'"$4"\
 '","param5": "'"$5"\
 '", "param6": "'"$6"\
 '", "param7": "'"$7"\
 '", "param8": "'"$8"\
 '","param9": "'"$9"\
 '", "param10": "'"${10}"\
 '", "param11": "'"${11}"\
 '"}'
```